# Выключить отображение ошибок

Tags: apache, php

```
**В php.ini:** error_reporting = E_NONE
**На странице index.php:** error_reporting(0);
**В htaccess**: 
php_flag display_errors On
#показать все ошибки кроме предупреждений (Notice)
php_value error_reporting "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE"
```

Ни один из вариантов не активировал скрытие ошибок

Comment: так то, что указано в htaccess наоборот включает отображение ошибок, попробуй
php_flag display_errors off

Comment: Да -я там ошибся. Даже с off не работает.

Comment: ini_get('display_errors') что возвращает? Да и эта запись не отключает, а наоборот включает отображение всех ошибок, кроме предупреждений php_value error_reporting "E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE"